# How to zip files with exclude list in linux/unix

Tags: file, zip

I have a list of files that I want to zip but I also have a list to exclude files and do not want them to be included in the zip archive.

so I have created a exclude.lst file and it has absolute path and filenames in it.

sample exclude file

`/home/logs/apache/access.log

/home/logs/tomcat/catalina.out`

but after using the below command, the zip command is not excluding the files rather archiving them.

`zip archives.2012.zip /home/logs/ -x@exclude.lst`

how can I overcome this ? and is there any other way to archive files by excluding the above files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating exclude.lst file, I'm assigning all the exclude files to a variable and passing those to the -x option in the zip.

For example

```
do_not_archive=/home/logs/apache/access.log /home/logs/tomcat/catalina.out
```

Then use zip as shown below

```
zip archives.2012.zip /home/logs/ -x $do_not_archive
```

Comment: This is not OP's question, he wanted to know how to use a list to exclude

Answer (score 2):

Old question, so zip may have changed since then, but from the man pages:

```
$man zip | grep -A2 exclude
```

> Also possible:
> zip -r foo foo -x@exclude.lst
> which will include the contents of foo in foo.zip while excluding all the files that match the patterns in the file exclude.lst.

I've confirmed that this works in Ubuntu 18, with each pattern/filename on a separate line (haven't tried separated by spaces)

Comment: How do you exclude files that contain a certain string or a pattern string? For example, I want to exclude all files that contain or end with `_ai1ec_parsed_css.css`.

Comment: @Pathros You use a regex to represent the patterns you want to exclude. Write the pattern in a file (one pattern per line) and use the "-x@{filename}" option

Comment: What does `grep`'s `-a2` do?  My man page says that `-a` doesn't take any additional qualifier.  It's Cygwin, which is Gnu, which is the same as Linux.

Comment: @user2153235 Looks like it should be -A now. (Uppercase). Fixed above

Answer (score 0):

Just a short addition to CBR's answer for the case you have a bunch of files to exclude (in my case files bigger than 10MB):

```sh
do_not_archive=$(find relative/path/to/directory -type f -size +10000000c)
zip -r backup_without_files_bigger_than_10mb.zip relative/path/to/directory -x $do_not_archive
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in two steps:

```
zip archive.zip -r -@ < include.lst
zip archive.zip -d -@ < exclude.lst
```

Comment: How do you exclude files that contain a certain string or a pattern string? For example, I want to exclude all files that contain or end with `_ai1ec_parsed_css.css`.